# open MainActivity using another activity java class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragmentactivity

I have made a simple canvas. but I want to make a new activity java class and open this activity using that activity java class. I have not used any layout files to make this class.
I want to know how can i make new activity before starting this and I won't open this java activity class using that. I have some idea using intent we can open them. but I haven't any clear idea.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Double> values;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));
    }

    public class MyView extends View{
        public MyView(Context context){
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            
            //Build Canvas
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            //Give the size
            int x = getWidth();
            int y = getHeight();
            int radius = 500;

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);

            // Add Values to ArrayList
            values = new ArrayList<>();
            values.add(20.1);
            values.add(21.9);
            values.add(21.3);
            values.add(21.4);
            values.add(20.5);
            values.add(21.6);
            values.add(21.7);

            //Generate Mean
            double sum = 0.0;
            for (double n : values){
                sum+= n;
            }

            try {
                double mean = sum/values.size();

                //Set Colors on Values
                if (mean <=50.0){
                    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#001a1a"));
                    canvas.drawCircle(x/2,y/2,radius,paint);
                    //Status show Toast
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong Input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#001a1a"));
                    toast.show();
                    Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please check about Values", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast2.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#001a1a"));
                    toast2.show();
                }
                else if (mean <=80.0){
                    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#87CEEB"));
                    canvas.drawCircle(x/2,y/2,radius,paint);
                    //Status show Toast
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hart rate is Low", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#87CEEB"));
                    toast.show();
                }
                else if(mean <=100.0){
                    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#B2BEB5"));
                    canvas.drawCircle(x/2,y/2,radius,paint);
                    //Status show Toast
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hart rate is Normal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#B2BEB5"));
                    toast.show();
                }
                else if(mean<=140.0){
                    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
                    canvas.drawCircle(x/2,y/2,radius,paint);
                    //Status show Toast
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hart rate is Very High", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
                    toast.show();

                }else{
                    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#001a1a"));
                    canvas.drawCircle(x/2,y/2,radius,paint);

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong Input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#001a1a"));
                    toast.show();
                    Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please check about Values", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast2.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#001a1a"));
                    toast2.show();

                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please check Values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use an `xml` file and put your class `MyView` there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create MainActivity2, and in AndroidManifest, change

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

from MainActivity to MainActivity2.

And in MainActivity2, using Intent to navigate to MainActivity

Comment: yes, I have done that.  I want to show canvas drawing on  MainActivity2 and after using that intent main activity. but at that time canvas doesn't show. because we need to call intent inside Oncreate method and after that create method I have build canvas.  I won't call that canvas inside the Oncreate method or somewhere to appear on that screen.